# group by only those values that are LIKE '[list of 3 values]'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have pandas dataframe. I want to select values from col1, that should have all 3  values in col2.
`col2_values_should start_with = [P1.adv, P2.cmp, P3.part ]`

 Also, since you can see the later part of values in col2, is dummy. so I need to use similar option as  LIKE operator of SQL in order to check col2 values.

[image]

so the answer from above table is:

[image]

because "A" has all the three values required, unlike B & C.

So basically I want to check which value in col1 has all the 3 required values in col2. and those col2 values should start with certain letters as mentioned above.

Edit:

Sample Data

ID  col1    col2

1   A   P1.adv abcd

2   A   P2.cmp mkmfwk

3   A   P3.part lpwf

4   B   P1.adv abcd

5   B   P2.cmp mkmfwk

6   C   P1.addv abcd

7   C   P1.adv abcd

Comment: please provide sample data in text format, otherwise it's harder to help

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it:

```
l = ('P1.adv', 'P2.cmp', 'P3.part' )
m1 = df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: x.col2.str.startswith(l, na=False)).reset_index()
m2 = df[m1.col2].groupby('col1').col2.nunique() > 2
df[df.col1.isin(m2[m2].index.values)]

   ID  col1         col2
0   1    A   P1.adv abcd
1   2    A  P2.cmp kmasd
2   3    A   P3.part lpw
```

**Explanation**

You can start by checking which rows in `df` contain a `col2` that starts with one of the items in the list using [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html).

```
print(m1)

 col1  level_1  col2
0    A        0  True
1    A        1  True
2    A        2  True
3    B        3  True
4    B        4  True
5    C        5  True
6    C        6  True
```

After you can groupby `col1` and check that the amount of unique items is greater than 2 (meaning that each of the elements in the list is present at least once) using [`GroupBy.nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
print(m2)

col1
A     True
B    False
C    False
Name: col2, dtype: bool
```

and finally use boolean indexing on the original `df` using `m2`:

```
result = df[df.col1.isin(m2[m2].index.values)]
print(result)

    ID  col1        col2
0   1    A   P1.adv abcd
1   2    A  P2.cmp kmasd
2   3    A   P3.part lpw
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex with `^` for match start of string and `|` for `OR`, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and compare `set`s, also is comparing if same length of groups like `list`:

```
L = ["P1.adv", "P2.cmp", "P3.part"]

pat = '|'.join(r"^{}".format(x) for x in L)
s = df['col2'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)

df = df[s.groupby(df['col1']).transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(L) and len(x) == len(L))]
print (df)
   ID col1           col2
0   1    A    P1.adv abcd
1   2    A  P2.cmp mkmfwk
2   3    A   P3.part 1pwf
```

Another solution is filter by [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html), then aggregate with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for counts, get number of unique values by [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and both compare by length of list, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `all` for check if both values are `True`s:

```
df = df[df['col2'].str.startswith(tuple(L))].copy()
m = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(['size','nunique']) == len(L)
df = df[df['col1'].isin(m.index[np.all(m, axis=1)])]
print (df)
   ID col1           col2
0   1    A    P1.adv abcd
1   2    A  P2.cmp mkmfwk
2   3    A   P3.part 1pwf
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP wants

Comment: @jezrael - its not a duplicate question. I need to constraint if col1 has certain values in col2 (not every value in col2)

Comment: In your 2nd solution, I'm getting memory error. However, in your 1st solution could you kindly tell, if there is no bracket missing?

Comment: @frozenshine - for me it working nice, there is some syntax error for you?

Comment: @frozenshine - added alternative solution, I hope no memory error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using regex and counting the occurrences of `A` being equal to the [pattern matches

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,1,1,5,5],'b':["abc.more","abcde.kef","abc.mop","lop.e","lop.e","get.le"]})
con = df.b.str.match('^(abc.m|lop.e)')
df['c'] = con
df['sum_c'] = df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('sum')
df['count_a'] = df.groupby('a')['a'].transform('count')
dff = df[df['count_a']==df['sum_c']]
dff
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary column in the dataframe that checks if any of the target prefix is present in col2. Then group them by col1 and sum. Then check if the sum is equal to 3

```
ans = (df.assign(temp = df.col2.str.startswith(tuple(col2_values_should_start_with)))\
         .groupby('col1')[['temp']].sum() == 3).reset_index()
```

Finaly, find the value of col1 that has the 3 starting strings

```
df[df['col1'].isin(list(ans[ans.temp == True].col1))]
```

Output:

```
    ID   col1       col2
    1    A    P1.advabcd
    2    A  P2.cmpmkmfwk
    3    A   P3.partlpwf
```